# Is there a `std::format` counterpart for string parsing?

Tags: c++, format, std, string-parsing, c++23

[`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) serves me well as a replacement of C-style `std::sprintf`. I'm not yet aware of any similar counterpart for string parsing. Is there a similar thing proposed for C++? I want to use it in place of C-style `std::sscanf`.

I'm aware of `operator>>`. It's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: maybe https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream? Yet it won't be the same syntax as you will not have a format string but you'll have to parse the string token by token with ```>>```

Comment: streams for simple cases, regexes for more complex ones

Comment: @AlanBirtles Regex is purely about string manipulation and does not handle input (into variables), right?

Comment: @Lingxi - You can of course use `getline` to input a string, and *then* use regex to parse the content. Or, if you are *really* daring, you have `regex_match` taking a pair of iterators. Could be input iterators, but I can't imagine how to sort that out if input fails...